# Bot creates a second channel for no reason

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have a big mistake. Everything works perfectly! But the bot creates two instead of one channel. Why is that? I've been trying to figure it out for myself. But I can't find the error.

````
    if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch(); 
    if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
    
    if (user.bot) return; 
    if (!reaction.message.guild) return; 
    if (reaction.message.guild.id !== "601109434197868574") return; 

    if (reaction.emoji.name === "") {
      if (reaction.message.channel.id === "732018576604528640");

      const channelName = `•┇ticket-${user.username}`
      if(reaction.message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel === `•┇ticket-${user.username}`)){
        return user.send("Du hast bereits ein offnes Ticket!")
      }
      reaction.message.guild.channels.create(channelName, {parent: '731947024932667432', topic: `Ticket Owner: ${user}`}).then(c => {
      const everyone = reaction.message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === '@everyone')
      const sr = reaction.message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'ticketsuppport')
      c.updateOverwrite(sr, {
        SEND_MESSAGES: true,
        VIEW_CHANNEL: true,
      });
      c.updateOverwrite(everyone, {
        SEND_MESSAGES: false,
        VIEW_CHANNEL: false,
      });
      c.updateOverwrite(user, {
        SEND_MESSAGES: true,
        VIEW_CHANNEL: true,
      });

      let GreetEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor(colours.maincolour)
      .setDescription(`> Guten Tag, ${user}!\n> \n> Du hast nun ein Support-Ticket erstellt. Wie können wir dir helfen?\n> \n> \ Ticket schließen | \ Weitere hilfe anfordern`)
      .setFooter(`Ticket erstellt`)
      .setTimestamp()
      c.send(GreetEmbed)

      let ping = c.send(`${user}`).then(message => {
        message.delete(ping)
      })

    })

    }```
````

Comment: Are you running the bot twice? Is it happening on a single reaction?

Comment: Its happening on a single reaction :c

Answer (score 0):

You most-likely have two instances of the bot running.

To verify this, you can make a change to the code (like modifying the message it sends when creating the channel). If both channels have the modification, I am wrong xD. If not, you need to find where your second bot it running (separate server, minimized window, etc..).

Comment: The bot only runs on my PC.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (reaction.message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === channelName)) {
    return user.send("Du hast bereits ein offenes Ticket!")
}
```

I think you forgot the `channel.name` because otherwise it filters for the channel object which will never be the same as a string and throughout that it'll never return. (BTW: There's also a typo with `offnes`)

Comment: Does the user even exist?

Comment: Yes. User is the reacter.

Comment: Something on my code is wrong but i dont know. My index.js is broke :c

Comment: Can you then please share your whole index file? Or I could join your Discord and talk to you this evening.

Comment: Here is the whole index file: https://workupload.com/file/ftjXhTTDnzd

Comment: Well, I noticed, that you have two `bot.login();`, please remove one of them. And I also noticed, that you use some events multiple times, I don't know whether this is support with discord.js but isn't a solution in many other frameworks.

Comment: OMG. Thank you so much. Now everything works fine. <3 Have a nice day ^^

Comment: You're welcome. You can also add these arguments to your bot: `const bot = new Discord.Client({
  partials: ['MESSAGE', 'CHANNEL', 'REACTION'],
});` this will allow uncached messages to be reacted to as well. And otherwise an error may occur.